# When to use curly bracket in data binding?

Tags: sapui5

In the demo kit of openui5, the section **Element Binding** involves two forms of data binding implementation.
As in the code below:

```js
var oMatrixLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout();
oMatrixLayout.bindElement("/company");
oMatrixLayout.createRow(
 new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Name:"}),
 new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{name}"})
);

oMatrixLayout.createRow(
 new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Revenue:"}),
 new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{revenue}"})
);
oMatrixLayout.createRow(
 new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Employees:"}),
 new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{employees}"})
);
```

When specifying the values for text fields, we use curly brackets({}) to indicate the value is from the model. However, in the code that immediately follows this one, no curly brackets are used:

```js
var data = {clients:[{firstName:"Donald", lastName:"Duck"}]};
...// create and set model here
var oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label("myLabel");
oLabel.bindProperty("text", "firstName");
oLabel.bindElement("/clients/0");
```

As you can see, no curly brackets are used in **oLabel.bindProperty("text", "firstName");**
So, what's the difference between the two examples? When to use curly brackets in data binding and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When to use brackets?**

While defining the controls along with the property use brackets: (**binding at RUNTIME**)

Example: `new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{name}"})`

and in terms of XML `<Label text="{name}"/>`

**When not to use brackets?** // **binding at a later time**

whenever you're using [**bindProperty**](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindProperty) method.

Read more about [property binding here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Comment: pretty straightforward and helpful

Comment: After a further thought on it, I made the following conclusion:

In places where an ordinary string is accepted for a value, curly brackets are needed to explicitly state that the actual value is from the model, instead of the literal string.

In places where an ordinary string is not expected as a value to be displayed on the UI, a string without curly brackets only serves to represent the binding path. That's the reason why curly brackets are not needed in this case.

Comment: yes you are correct.. Hence when we use bindProperty, bindElement is also used along with that